# breakpoints in flask jinja templates

Tags: python, debugging, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to put breakpoints in a jinja template that is being rendered from flask ?  Maybe something that can enable you do inspect the variables that are available to the template at various points in the template ?  Ive seen a blog that says you can do it in django https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/05/16/putting-breakpoints-to-html-templates-in-python/ was hoping for something similar with flask.

Answer (score -1):

Flask has `app_context_processor` make variables available on templates:

> Context processors run before the template is rendered and have the ability to inject new values into the template context.

```
class Letters():
    A = 1
    B = 2

@app.context_processor
def share_context():
    return dict(Letters=Letters)

Now you can access this class

# index.html
{{ Letters.A }}
{% if Letters.B != 1 %}
...
{% endif %}
```

[flask context processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/#context-processors)